# Android 8+ Background BLE Scanning for All New Beacons

Tags: android, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have successfully used an AlarmManager to periodically scan for BLE beacons (advertisers) in the past, but we are running into the very common issues with Android 8.1+. Specifically - our BroadcastReceiver is not being triggered by the AlarmManager when our app has been in the background for awhile.

David Young has an excellent Blog entry describing this common challenge here:
http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8

It clarifies that Android 8.1+ can be setup using StartScan to call a BroadcastReceiver when a new beacon is scanned by the OS. All good. The blog entry goes on to clarify that, while this new beacon is still scannable, no BroadcastReceiver triggers will occur - even when new beacons are scanned (with different IDs than the first scanned beacon). Not good. The Blog entry goes on to describe how app explicit scanning can occur - but that scans may only be started by the Job Scheduler with intervals as high as every 25 min.

In our application, we need to see when every beacon is newly scanned (i.e. it has just been turned on or come into range). We do not need to track if it is still scannable. Critically - we must be able to find additional beacons that come into range or get turned on while the original beacon is still scannable. Also critical is that we can get the BroadcastReceiver quickly for these additional beacons (think 30 sec or less).

Is there a technique that supports re-starting scanning to get BroadcastReceiver for every beacon when it is newly scanned (i.e. scanned for the first time)? For example, can we stop and restart scanning when a beacon is scanned for the first time? There must be a way to do this. I cannot believe that Android would limit new beacon detection to every 25 min if another beacon has already been scanned and is still scannable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure JobScheduler is limited to 15 minutes, not 25. Why not use a foreground service and a Handler, if you need something more frequent than 15 minutes?

Comment: It's the recommended way to have something execute on a short interval. You postDelayed the action you want, and then at the end of the action, you postDelayed it again.

Comment: @MarkKeen except that it no longer works in Android 8.1.

Comment: @MarkKeen I'm not sure if you're being sarcastic or not (sorry, just a reflex), but yes, it should. It just needs to be run in a foreground service.

Comment: A foreground service requires user visibility of the app and this is certainly not desirable. In fact, this might be a deal breaker. Re 25 min - this is based on comments by David Young in his blogs. Both 15 and 25 min are both far too long.

Comment: I don't think there's any alternative.

Comment: My thinking was that there must be a way to use the approach described in David's Blog (his "The New Way: Fast Detections" section), but without the constraint that any newly discovered beacons will be missed whenever the first scanned beacon is still scanable. We do not need to track how long beacons can be scanned, we just need a BroadcastReceiver trigger when all are scanned for the first time.

Comment: The first method isn't saying that. It's saying that if no new beacons are discovered within 15 minutes, the app will be killed.

Comment: I am interpreting it differently. It states "Using the above, we can get a detection of the first new beacon being around when our app isn’t running on Android 8... ". Perhaps I am putting too much weight on the use of "first". This suggests that I have to scan after the first beacon is scanned - in order to get additional beacons. And - I cannot scan very frequently. I will try the example code with 2 different beacons to see if both signal the BroadcastReceiver.